# Syntax error, unexpected '.' in ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php

Tags: magento2, php, cron, cli

I am trying to install Magento, but it showing me error:

> syntax error, unexpected '.' in
>   E:\wamp\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93

as per the suggestion's I had upgrade my php version. The problem is solve for temporary. After completion of installation the message show as:

> System messages
>
> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
>   running.

On searching on this topic I got suggestion to run following command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

but on running of this command it shows me error again:

> syntax error, unexpected '.' in
>   E:\wamp\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93

Comment: what is ur current php version ?

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: ***wrong version of the php is a main issue***

Try to run this command in command line:

```
php -v
```

It is possible that your cli php is different from the server's php (cli php version is older than php version used by your server). If this is so, try to change path to the php used in cli.

Your problem occurs in a line of arguments of this method:

```
protected function createObject($type, $args)
{
    return new $type(...array_values($args));
}
```

becouse your cli php can not understand (parse) the `...` symbols ([Argument Unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking)) that is available for the php versions >= 5.6 .

**PS:** Here you can find an answer for the question ["How to check php version on windows command line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517718/php-version-on-windows-command-line)

Comment: Just got this issue, and it turns out I was using PHP 5.5 so changed to PHP 7 and it was fixed :)

Comment: @Zubair1 I'm glad to hear it :) As I said, wrong version of the php is a main issue.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau I am using PHP 7.0.33 (cli) still facing same issue in magento 2 running installation.

Comment: @Rahul seems like magento instalation (web server) use another version of the php. What says `phpinfo()` if you run it from web browser/curl?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau php -v shows PHP 7.0.33  and phpinfo() shows PHP/7.0.33

Comment: @Rahul Hmm, it's strange issue. Could you test in browser\curl with custom script, like: `function testSum ($a, $b, $c) {
    return $a + $b + $c;
}
$arr = [1,2,3];
echo testSum(...$arr);`? Will return 6 when you opet in in web-browser\curl.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in Magento 2.1.5 at the time of installation, and resolve the issue with update php version >= 5.6.